# import CSS in sharepoint 2010

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

seen like this is the easy way, 
but I am facing some issue, 
I separated style sheet according to the section 
like

```
layout.css 
typo.css
element.css
```

and sooo on

and then from the masterpage section I added the 1 stylesheet named 'style'
and call all the style sheet into it using the "@import url('typo.css')"

the problem is this @import is not working...
any solution how to call all other .css in 1 stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on where the style sheets are located on filesystem or style library. @import directive will not work for a style library.

I will suggest you skip the import directive and add the three style declarations in your master page.

Comment: registering the css in masterpage directly usually crush the page. the best way to add SiteSetting>MasterPage>Alternate CSS URL. and all the other css are located in same place where the style.css is but its not importing other css.